# Dereferencing pointer to arbitrary address gives Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, dereference

I have written a simple C code for pointers. As per my understanding, Pointer is a variable which holds the address of another variable. 
Eg :

```
 int x = 25; // address - 1024
 int *ptr = &x;
 printf("%d", *ptr); // *ptr will give value at address of x i.e, 25 at 1024 address.
```

However when I try below code I'm getting segmentation fault

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    int *ptr = 25;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong in this?  Why can't a pointer variable return the value at address 25?  Shouldn't I be able to read the bytes at that address?

Comment: ` int *ptr = 25;` is telling that `ptr` will point to the address `25`. How is it even related to the other numbers you are mentioning - I have no idea.

Comment: Yes. `ptr` is pointing to address `25`. Why printing `*ptr` is giving seg fault. It has to give value at address `25`

Comment: You had it right the first time: `int x = 25; int *ptr = &x; printf("%d", *ptr);` is perfectly fine. `int *ptr = 25; printf("%d", *ptr);` is garbage code.

Comment: @Cynacode How do you know address 25 is valid and is correctly aligned for addressing an `int`? If you think you know it is valid and correctly aligned, then it appears that the system disagrees, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agree with you. However `printf("%d", ptr);` will properly print the value `25` how is this happening ?

Comment: @Cynacode `printf("%d", ptr);` happens to work in your case although it is incorrect. The correct way to print a pointer is `printf("%p", (void *)ptr);`. If you really want to print the pointer as an integer, you would need to cast it like `prinf("%d", (int)ptr);`. None of the above dereference the pointer, they just (or attempt to) print the pointer value. However, `printf("%d", *ptr);` _does_ dereference the pointer, resulting in the segmentation fault because the pointer is invalid.

Comment: If you want ptr points to address #25 of memory use: `int *ptr=(int *) 25;
    printf("%p", ptr);`

Comment: But as your program not access to this address of any other address, you face with seg fault by use: `printf("%d", *ptr);`

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're running on an embedded system with specific known memory locations, you can't assign an arbitrary value to a pointer an expect to be able to dereference it successfully.

Section 6.5.3.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states the following regarding the indirection operator `*`:

> The unary
>   `*` operator denotes indirection.  If the operand points to a function, the result is a  function  designator;  if  it  points  to  an 
>   object,  the  result  is  an  lvalue  designating  the object.   If 
>   the  operand  has  type  "pointer  to type",  the  result  has 
>   type  "type".   **If  an invalid  value  has  been  assigned  to 
>   the  pointer,  the  behavior  of  the  unary
>   `*` operator  is undefined.**

As mentioned in the passage above, the C standard only allows for pointers to point to known objects or to dynamically allocated memory (or `NULL`), not arbitrary memory locations.  Some implementations may allow that in specific situations, but not in general.

Answer (score 5):

Although the behavior of your program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) according to the C standard, your code is actually correct in the sense that it is doing exactly what you intend. It is attempting to read from memory address 25 and print the value at that address.

However, in most modern operating systems, such as Windows and Linux, programs use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and not physical memory. Therefore, you are most likely attempting to access a virtual memory address that is not mapped to a physical memory address. Accessing an unmapped memory location is illegal and causes a segmentation fault.

Since the memory address 0 (which is written in C as `NULL`) is normally reserved to specify an invalid memory address, most modern operating systems never map the first few kilobytes of virtual memory addresses to physical memory. That way, a segmentation fault will occur when an invalid NULL pointer is dereferenced (which is good, because it makes it easier to detect bugs).

For this reason, you can be reasonably certain that also the address 25 (which is very close to address 0) is never mapped to physical memory and will therefore cause a segmentation fault if you attempt to access that address.

However, most other addresses in your program's [virtual memory address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) will most likely have the same problem. Since the operating system tries to save physical memory if possible, it will not map more virtual memory address space to physical memory than necessary. Therefore, trying to guess valid memory addresses will fail, most of the time.

If you want to explore the virtual address space of your process to find memory addresses that you can read without a segmentation fault occuring, you can use the appropriate API supplied by your operating system. On Windows, you can use the function [`VirtualQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery). On Linux, you can read the pseudo-filesystem [`/proc/self/maps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). The ISO C standard itself does not provide any way of determining the layout of your virtual memory address space, as this is operating system specific.

If you want to explore the virtual memory address layout of other running processes, then you can use the [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) function on Windows and read `/proc/[pid]/maps` on Linux. However, since other processes have a separate virtual memory address space, you can't access their memory directly, but must use the [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) and [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) functions on Windows and use `/proc/[pid]/mem` on Linux.

Disclaimer: Of course, I don't recommend messing around with the memory of other processes, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

However, as a programmer, you normally don't want to explore the virtual memory address space.  Instead, you normally work with memory that has been assigned to your program by the operating system. If you want the operating system to give you some memory to play around with, which you are allowed to read from and write to at will (i.e. without segmentation faults), then you can just declare a large array of chars (bytes) as a global variable, for example `char buffer[1024];`. Be careful with declaring larger arrays as local variables, as this may cause a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). Alternatively, you can ask the operating system for dynamically allocated memory, for example using the `malloc` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider all warnings that the compiler issues.

This statement

```
int *ptr = 25;
```

is incorrect. You are trying to assign an integer to a pointer as an address of memory. Thus in this statement

```
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

there is an attempt to access memory at address 25 that does not belong to your program.

What you mean is the following

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main( void )
{
    int x = 25;

    int *ptr = &x;

    printf("%d", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( void )
{
    int *ptr = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    *ptr = 25;

    printf("%d", *ptr);

    free( ptr );

    return 0;
}
```