# Dereferencing pointer cast from an integer of a valid memory address give Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, dereference

I was playing around with c pointer and wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 17;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = (int*)(&p1);
    p1 = (int*)(&p2);
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)(*p1)));
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)(*p2)));
    return 0;
}
```

the program exit with

```
[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 0.23 seconds
```

the pointers work as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 17;
    int* p1 = &a;
    int* p2 = (int*)(&p1);
    p1 = (int*)(&p2);
    printf("&p1 %d\n", &p1);
    printf("&p2 %d\n", &p2);
    printf("p1 %d\n", p1);
    printf("p2 %d\n", p2);
    printf("*p1 %d\n", *p1);
    printf("*p2 %d\n", *p2);
    // printf("%d\n", *((int*)(*p1)));
    // printf("%d\n", *((int*)(*p2)));
    return 0;
}
```

```
&p1 748680992
&p2 748680984
p1 748680984
p2 748680992
*p1 748680992
*p2 748680984
```

it only stopped working when i try to dereference arbitrary-ish address

according to the answers from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187160/dereferencing-pointer-to-arbitrary-address-gives-segmentation-fault), the reason dereferencing arbitrary memory address doesn't work is because the address is invalid

but here i dereference an address that i was able to dereference just fine before

is this because of some kind of protection to prevent bad code? if so i want to know the specifics of the protection mechanism
or i'm just doing it wrong for what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Dereferencing p2 is UB since it doesn't point to an int.

Comment: `int* p2 = (int*)(&p1);` is wrong.  `p1` is a *pointer*, not an `int`.  Why did you add the `(int*)` cast?  Was that added to make a warning or error message go away?  Using casts to make warnings or errors disappear indicates you did something wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i wanted to interpret the address of p1 as the address of an integer

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pointers and integers do not necessarily have the same size. Messing around that way is asking for trouble.

Comment: You must use `%p` to print pointers. And you need to cast to `void*`

Comment: @Gerhardh casting to void* give the error "invalid use of void expression". I just want to know how or what figured out what i was trying to do is not allowed because from what i can understand, the value i dereference normally and the value i dereference using a weird cast is the same value

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh i figured it out after reading your comment more carefully, it was indeed because of the difference in type size that my code didn't work, casting to long long* solved it

Comment: `void*` is not a void expression. Did you forget the `*`?

Answer (score 1):

Lets work through all your printf's,

- &p1 and &p2 are just addresses ( of pointers )
- p1 and p2 are just addresses too
- *p1, p1 is set to the address of p2 so *p1 will be p2
- *p2, p2 is set to the address of p1 so *p2 will be p1

There is never an arbitrary address being dereferenced, so no segfaults.

printf is probably just casting pointers to ints.

Try `printf( "%ld\n", (uintptr_t)&p1 );` `ld` for long int, `uintptr_t` is casting a pointer to unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dereference a pointer if it does not correctly point to an object, or it causes undefined behavior (i.e., anything strange can happen).

Also note that the address of a "pointer" should be stored in "pointer to pointer".

Following are some examples:

```
int a = 42;

// This is a pointer to int. (It points to a.)
int *p = &a;

// A pointer to pointer to int. (It points to p.)
int **q = &p;

// This is okay: types match and *q == &a.
p = *q;

// This is also okay: types match and &(*q) == &p.
q = &(*q);

// If you write incorrect assignment such as:
// p = &q;
// Then you are likely to get a warning from compiler, since their types are different.
```